# What's wrong with this line of code in my batch script?

Tags: powershell, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to assign the freespace on Disk C: to a variable using this command, and I can't seem to get it to function at properly.

```
For /f "tokens=3" %%A IN ('powershell -noprofile -command "get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter \"DeviceID = 'C:'"" ^| Find "FreeSpace"') DO Set _FreeSpace=%%A
```

It doesn't assign the variable anything. When running the powershell script directly inside of the ISE, it gives the expected result. And running the code in the parentheses inside of CMD directly (changing the ^| to |) works fine as well.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious as this is my first time really getting into For commands, but any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For starters, it looks as if you may be missing an escape character, `\"DeviceID = 'C:'""` should probably be `\"DeviceID = 'C:'\""`. I have no idea though why you're piping its result through `find.exe` though, instead of doing it within the powershell instance.

Comment: Adding the escape character doesn't work.
Also, wasn't sure how to do it in powershell. Assumed it would be just as easy to do it the way I am. I guess not though lol

Comment: I didn't say it did or even would work, I merely pointed out that you'd escaped the first inner doublequote, but not the second one.

Comment: purely out of curiosity ... WHY are you mixing Bat/CMD with Powershell code? this is all very easily done in pure powershell.

Comment: Easier to run on multiple machines in my experience. Also, I do not have much experience with Powershell. Mainly CMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `=` is a standard token separator in `cmd.exe` just like the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> you need to properly escape it (note that `\` is nothing special to `cmd.exe` so the `=` appears unquoted):

```cmd
for /F "tokens=3" %%A in ('powershell -noprofile -command "get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter \"DeviceID ^= 'C:'\"" ^| Find "FreeSpace"') do set "_FreeSpace=%%A"
```

Answer (score 2):

Hard to get all those single and double quotes to work with powershell and then inside a for loop.  This seems to work for me:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_cmdToRun=powershell -noprofile -command "get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter \"DeviceID = 'C:'"""
For /f "tokens=3" %%A IN ('!_cmdToRun! ^| Find "FreeSpace"') DO Set _FreeSpace=%%A
```

Answer (score 0):

I would offer this alternative, which will additionally provide the result in GB:

```
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Powershell -NoP^
 "gWMI Win32_LogicalDisk -F \""DeviceID='C:'\""|"^
 "%%{[Math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}"'
)Do @Set "FDS=%%G"
@Echo Freespace on C: is %FDS%GB
@Timeout -1
```

or the simpler:

```
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Powershell -NoP^
 "[Math]::Round($(gWMI Win32_LogicalDisk -F \""DeviceID='C:'\"").FreeSpace/1GB,2)"
')Do @Set "FDS=%%G"
@Echo Freespace on C: is %FDS%GB
@Timeout -1
```

---

Based upon your comment, if you want it in bytes, you could use:

```
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Powershell -NoP^
 "gWMI Win32_LogicalDisk -F \""DeviceID='C:'\""|Select -Exp FreeSpace"
')Do @Set "FDS=%%G"
@Echo Freespace on C: is %FDS%bytes
@Timeout -1
```

or the simpler:

```
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Powershell -NoP^
 "(gWMI Win32_LogicalDisk -F \""DeviceID='C:'\"").FreeSpace"
')Do @Set "FDS=%%G"
@Echo Freespace on C: is %FDS%bytes
@Timeout -1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, having it in GB isn't quite what I'm looking for in this case. But I'm sure I'll need to use it eventually. Thanks!

Comment: @C.Kellerman, I have added some additional examples to assist you in that regard, and decided to use backslash escaping to hopefully make it easier to understand.